# Can't connect to Internet on any wifi but my own

Tags: wireless, internet, 23.04

I can connect to the internet wirelessly on my home LAN, but nowhere else.  Connecting to the WiFi works well but I just can't get to the internet.  Ubuntu 23.04 running on a Dell Latitude 5590.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a pihole at home by any chance? If so you will need an alternative DNS server configured

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Exactly what should I be looking for?  I can connect to the wifi but I can't get to the internet.  And if a pihole has anything to do with Raspberry Pi, no I'm not using one.